# Finding overlap between two tables, and percentage in SQL

Tags: sql

I have two tables.

One with customer information (including Zip Code).
Second is all zip codes around the States.

I am trying to find two things:

1. Which zip codes overlap from the customer information table and the entire zip codes table?
2. The percentage of customers per Zip code - so something that overlaps the two tables to see the ratio of customers in each zip code...

I am having a lot of trouble with this. I don't really know where to start. Can anyone advise on a starting point? I am new to SQL.

My initial thought is to have the main query, then the subquery with some sort of a join. But I am struggling to come up with anything.

Edit: Expected output is a column with the overlapping zip codes, and a column with the percentage of customers in that zip code.

Comment: Seems this can be done with an outer join, and an aggregation. Can't tell for sure, though. Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: The tag `sql` says: "Structured Query Language (SQL) is a language for querying databases. Questions should include code examples, table structure, sample data, **and a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.) being used**. If your question relates solely to a specific DBMS (uses specific extensions/features), use that DBMS's tag instead. Answers to questions tagged with SQL should use ISO/IEC standard SQL."

Answer (score 0):

With `customers`, `zipcodes` your tables; and `code` the filed for the zipcode in each table, and `id` some customer id.

Try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT zipcodes.code from zipcodes LEFT JOIN customers on customers.code = zipcodes.code
```

for the overlapping zipcodes

and

```
WITH us_count as (
    SELECT COUNT(*) from zipcodes
    LEFT JOIN customers ON customers.code = zipcodes.code) 
SELECT customers.code, 100 * COUNT(customers.id)/us_count  FROM zipcodes LEFT JOIN customers ON customers.code = zipcodes.code GROUP BY customers.code
```

Comment: `UNIQUE` should be `DISTINCT`   At least in most DBMS's, like MySQL and  MSSQL.

Comment: Oops my bad, corrected, thanks !

Comment: Hi Plain! I am trying this but am getting an error:

'SELECT DISTINCT zip_codes.zip from zip_codes LEFT JOIN customers on customers.zip = zip_codes.zip,
WITH us_count as (
    SELECT COUNT(zip) from zip_codes
    LEFT JOIN customers ON customers.zip = zip_codes.zip) 
SELECT customers.zip, 100 * COUNT(customers.zip)/us_count FROM zip_codes LEFT JOIN customers ON customers.zip = zip_codes.zip
GROUPBY customers.zip'

Comment: @TheDon: You should always (also) tell about the error message. In this case it might be the `GROUPBY` which should contain a space, and be written as `GROUP BY`.    Also: you cannot combine 2 queries by putting the one after the other with a ',' in between. AFAIK there is noo DBMS which likes that.